# Wrap innerText in a HTML tag without affecting anything in else innerHTML

Tags: jquery

Sorry about the really crap title, it's difficult to explain. A simplified version... I have the following markup:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/product/collection"><span class="collection">View</span> this collection today.</a>
```

Now, what i'm trying to end up with is the following:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/product/collection"><span class="collection">View</span> this <span class="someClass">collection</span> today.</a>
```

And I can mostly do this with the following:

```
var $el = $('a');
var newHTML = $el.html().replace(/collection/g, '<span class="someClass">collection</span>');
$el.html(newHTML);
```

The problem is though, we end up with:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/product/collection"><span class="<span class="someClass">collection</span>">View</span> this <span class="someClass">collection</span> today.</a>
```

Which obviously isn't what I want... Am I going about this arse about face? Should I be doing this a different way?

This is a very simple example, the word might be something other than "collection" and might appear multiple times within the elements text. I have also tried using $.text() but the span tags get escaped, as you would expect, and appear as the text "collection".

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I have edited the examples as they were completely wrong and not what I was asking about at all! Sorry!

Comment: Try this `/ collection /g`.  There are better ways, but just a quick fix attempt.  Why do you want to do this.

Comment: have you tried using `$el.innerHTML = newHTML` instead of the jquery `.html()`?

Comment: Hi @Nick yeah I tried that, same result as adding it via .text(), the html tags get escaped...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('a:contains(collection)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('collection', '<span class="someClass">collection</span>');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hgJCh/)**

The resultant HTML is:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/product/collection">View this <span class="someClass">collection</span> today.</a>
```

If you wanted to replace the word collection multiple times, change the replace line to:

```
.replace(/collection/g, '<span class="someClass">collection</span>')
```

Comment: Thanks, however, after reading your comment I realised my examples were actually just nonsense. I have updated them with what I was actually asking.

Comment: Just replace the return line with `return $(this).html().replace('collection', '<span class="someClass">collection</span>');`. The only change in that line is html() to text(). http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hgJCh/1/

Comment: If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/hgJCh/2/ you'll see that changing to .text() strips out the original span around the word "View". I want to maintain all old tags but just adding in the one new one.